# ListView / GridView: Setting child layout properly

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, gridview, android-adapter

I want to create a `ListView` (same question is relevant for a `GridView`) where the items have very specific `LayoutParams`. Take this example where I want each row to be a `LinearLayout` with a height of `100dp`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pd_textview"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I use this XML layout with a standard `BaseAdapter` implementation of `getView()` that inflates the views none of the `LayoutParams` for my `LinearLayout` get applied (each row simply wraps around the size of the text in the `TextView`):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Inflate view if necessary
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(ID_LAYOUT, null, false);
    }

    // Return the view
    return convertView;
}
```

Fishing around in the appropriate section of the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html), it says the following about `getView()` which explains the current behaviour:

> Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the
>   data set. You can either create a View manually or inflate it from an
>   XML layout file. When the View is inflated, the parent View (GridView,
>   ListView...) will apply default layout parameters unless you use
>   inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) to specify a root view
>   and to prevent attachment to the root.

My question is simply, how should I actually be doing this? The suggestion of using a root view with the desired `LayoutParams` seems convoluted given that the `LayoutParams` I want to inflate the view with are in the view that I'm trying to inflate (yes I could inflate a static view and leave it as a member of the class to reference against... but that seems silly). The other option would be to only define the contents of the row item in XML and manually create the container and its `LayoutParams` every time?

Is there a 'correct' way (i.e. not a wasteful hack) that I'm missing to simply create items with the `LayoutParams` defined in the XML?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the height of the row item is not 100dp in the `ListView`?

Comment: Yes, when this code is run I end up with a `ListView`of items that are the size of the text in the `TextView` - not a `ListView` of items that are 100dp high

Comment: You could assign them `height` in the `getView` method.

Comment: Passing `parent` as an argument to `inflate` should solve the issue. `inflate(ID_LAYOUT, parent, false);`

Comment: That works, but I can't see how it makes any sense given that the documentation for `inflate()` for `root` says "Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)". It should be taking the `LayoutParams` of parent based on that definition which it was already doing? Confused...

Comment: @BT the explanation for this behavior could be found here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70#t=3219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have preferred to put this in a comment, but I don't have the 50 reputation needed to do that...

There is detailed explanation of the issue here:

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

The main point is this:

"The problem with this is android:layout_xxx attributes are always be evaluated in the context of the parent view. As a result, without any known parent, all LayoutParams you declared on the root element of your XML tree will just get thrown away [,...]"

So, indeed, the solution is:

```
    convertView = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(ID_LAYOUT, parent, false);
```